# Composer Autoload.php not loading in Namespaces and Classes on live hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I have a simple PHP web app with the following structure:

```
/         (composer.json .htaccess ...)  
/Core/    (Router.php, Controller.php ...)    
/App/     (/Controllers, /Models, /Views ...)    
/Public/  (index.php ...)  
/Vendor/  (autoload.php /composer ...)
```

The codes runs without issue on my local server.

When I copy it to a live server and make the necessary changes to .htaccess in route I get the following error:  Fatal error: Class 'Core\Router' not found in.... I have tried 3 different hosts but no luck.

The issue seems to be to do with the composer autoload function not loading in the namespaces and classes using psr-4.  I have this set up in my composer.json file:

```
{
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         "Core\\": "Core/",
         "App\\": "App/"
    }
}
```

The code for my project is on GitHub at

https://github.com/imoprojects/upbook

I am new to programming in an MVC structure and also with using composer in this way.

If anyone could assist with what maybe happening, I would really appreciate it.

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: Have you did `composer install` on the server after copying your project? If you copy files including vendor folder do `composer dump` to refresh autoloader.

Comment: As a sidenote you should not commit your vendor directory. That's supposed to be automatically generated via `composer install` on every deploy. You are supposed to commit your `composer.lock` if any.

Comment: @apokryfos for some reason composer does not generate a composer.lock file when I run composer install .  I assumed it was because I am not pulling in any third party libraries?  Thank you for the advice, I will ignore it from the commit next time

Comment: @IMO your particular case there wouldn't be one generated because you're not requiring any additional packages. That's why I added the "if any" part at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You configure this:

```
"Core\\": "Core/",
```

... but your classes are at:

```
core
```

This will only work in case insensitive file systems.

Comment: Thank you @Álvaro that has been causing me so much trouble.  Is there a standard that I should be following in terms of naming folders and files?  I am new to development and I am trying to learn good practice.

Comment: Great thanks, I will read the docs this time :) ... lots to learn!

Comment: WOW what a pity, it was driving me crazy for the past 12 hours... Never thought such a simple difference between OS can have such a huge impact. Even worse only one of hundreds of files had a wrong case!!!! I am gonna dance this evening.